# How can i install Tkinter on Windows 10?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i install Tkinter on Windows 10?
I have tried everything. I use PyCharm. I put my code to repl.it and it worked as it should. But i like PyCharm and i want to use it for my coding. Can it be that it does not support tkinter?

Comment: `tkinter` should be included in Python installation if you have selected it during installation.

Comment: Just a thought - you're not on Python2? I think `tkinter` is `Tkinter` in that case. (when importing)

Answer (score 3):

`tkinter` is a built-in python module. so when you install python, `tkinter` is installed too. here is more clarification: 
when you want to install python you have 2 option:

1. Install Now: this is some kind of standard installation. most of the programs have it.
   [image]
2. Customize Installation: when using this option you can choose which modules to install. in this picture, you will see `tcl/tk and IDLE` which contains `tkinter` module. make sure it is checked!

   [image]

- you can see here there is nothing wrong with using tkinter and PyCharm.
  [image]

  if you still get the error, I suggest reinstalling your python. probably the best way.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is built-in in python so no need to install it. Also, I have Windows 10 and I have just finished doing a massive project with tkinter and pycharm and it as worked fine. Be aware tho, when you are trying to import tkinter watch out for the suggestion that pycharm tries to give you: the right name for the module is tkinter and not _tkinter

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that TKinter is already installed on your computer, to test it just try to write "import TKinter" and most likely after you have written "import TKin" the rest will highlight, to be extra sure that it is installed write tkinter._test() and if it doesn't work try to reinstall python
Also maybe this can be helpful:
https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Tkinter

EDIT: Like with other modules make sure you don't name your folder or file TKinter because this can cause problems