# Can not use tkinter even I already install

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a UI for desktop application. And I use tkinter for UI.
I install tkinter using pip

```
pip install tk
```

It show me that I successfully install tkinter

```
Downloading tk-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Installing collected packages: tk
Successfully installed tk-0.1.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/navin/voice-transform/test_dir/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But when I try to use it I'm not able to use the library

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "me.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Comment: tkinter already installed with python

Comment: Try reinstalling python as `tkinter` is an in-built library and needs no installation

Comment: `tkinter` is ***not*** `tk`; `tk` is just a common _abbreviation_ for `tkinter`, used when importing it. When you run `pip install tk`, what you're actually installing is [this](https://pypi.org/project/tk/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a Linux distrubion like Ubuntu then you have to use the `apt` command

```sh
sudo apt install python3-tk
```

If you use Widows then you have to use the executable they provide on their website. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63032937/18419414)

Answer (score 2):

`pip install tk` installs the tensorkit package, *not* tkinter. You cannot install tkinter with pip.